Engineering Dynamics Problem: Torque Comparison for Single Rod in Upward vs Downward Swing
I am currently researching the upward and downward swinging motions of landing gear mechanisms. I aim to determine whether there is a torque difference for the rod during the upward and downward swings.
From a mechanical perspective, the downward swing is aided by gravity, which accelerates the motion, whereas the upward swing must overcome gravitational resistance. Therefore, the maximum torque during the upward swing is typically greater than that during the downward swing. Is this understanding correct?
For simplicity, I am first analyzing a single rod. I am using Newton's method to calculate the torque, as well as applying the principle of work and energy.
Here are my free body diagram and mass acceleration diagram.

According to these diagrams, drive torque formula can be defined as:

input Data:

I assume this linkage operates at a constant speed, so the angular acceleration during
operation is zero.
Calculate the instantaneous driving torque when θ1 equals 150 degrees.

Newton's Method


Ti = W1∙rG1∙cos_θ1 = 2∙9.81∙0.075∙cos150°=-1.274 N-m (Downward Swing)


(The torque of upward swing the same.)


Energy and Momentum Methods


Ti = [(Ek2+Ug2)-(Ek1+Ug1)]/Δθ1


Ek2-Ek1=0 (because angular velocity is constant.)


∆Ug=Ug2-Ug1=m1∙g∙rg1∙(sin150°-sin149°)=2∙9.81∙0.075∙-0.015=-0.022


Ti = -0.022/Δθ1 = -0.022/0.01745rad = -1.26 N-m (Downward Swing)


∆Ug=Ug2-Ug1=m1∙g∙rg1∙(sin150°-sin151°)=2∙9.81∙0.075∙-0.015 = 0.022


Ti = 0.022/Δθ1 = -0.022/0.01745rad = 1.26 N-m (upward wing)

Through two methods, the instantaneous torque obtained is essentially the same. During the downward swing, the torque is negative because the speed is insufficient to counteract the weight, requiring braking. During the upward swing, the torque is positive as the system provides energy
Here comes the problem. My analysis results seem to indicate that under constant speed conditions, the torque is primarily influenced by the weight alone. As a result, the torque values for both upward and downward swings are essentially the same, differing only in their sign (positive or negative). However, this seems to contradict the previously mentioned mechanical understanding.
Could anyone provide insights or confirm this understanding?Thanks.

What about the speed of the aircraft? won't retracting be aided by the force of the air and extending must counter it??

Since you are assuming constant angular velocity in each case and are assuming all the usual simplifications Newton 2 tells you no torque is required because acceleration is zero and so you are just left with reacting the weight, which depends on position and not velocity.

It makes perfect sense. when we remove the acceleration, we are left with only torque caused by $\tau= mgr*cos\theta$
For simplicity, I assume the rod's mass is concentrated at the end; it wouldn't affect the outcome!
$$\tau= mgr*cos\theta +\frac{\Delta L}{\Delta t}$$

L =I$\omega$
$\omega$= angular rotation speed in radians
r is the length of the landing rod
I = moment of inertia of rod
$\theta$ = the angle with horizon

If we keep the $\omega$ constant, the angular momentum's derivative WRT time , $\frac{\Delta L}{\Delta t}$ will be zero. So both upward and downward, and even pausing the rotation, will have equal torque!
